# how to display data from webservice in listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to show data from webservice in listbox in wp. The data in the websevice contains  3 fields along with an image and the data has to be refeshed i.e when new data is entered it should come first. As i am building my first app i am finding it a bit difficult. Please help. My .cs code till now is

```
namespace KejriwalPhoneApp
{
    public partial class News : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public class Newss
    {
        public string News_Title { get; set; }
        public string News_Description { get; set; }
        public string Date_Start { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewsList: List<Newss>
    {
        public NewsList()
        {


        }
    }

    public News()
         {
             InitializeComponent();

            KejriwalService.aapSoapClient myClient = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
            myClient.getarvindNewsCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs>(myClient_getarvindNewsCompleted);
            myClient.getarvindNewsAsync();

         }

       void myClient_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
          {
              listBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result;

          }

   }
}
```

My dataset is:

```
<string><NewDataSet>
  <UserDetails>
    <id>5</id>
    <News_Title>Audit of Electricity Companies</News_Title>
    <News_Description> Rejecting the contention of private power distributors, the Delhi government today ordered an audit of their finances by the government's national auditor or Comptroller and Auditor General (CAG), fulfilling yet another election promise of the Aam Aadmi Party.

&amp;quot;We have ordered an audit of the private power distribution companies. The CAG has said it will do the audit,&amp;quot; Chief Minister Arvind Kejriwal said. He also said Lieutenant Governor Najeeb Jung's order on the audit of the companies will go to CAG Shashi Kant Sharma tomorrow.</News_Description>
<Date_Start>2014-01-03</Date_Start>
<image_path>news.png</image_path>
```

From here i need to show the news_title, news_Description, Date_Start, image in one list which should be clickable and there will be more than 1 data

My xaml file is

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" Margin="38,86,38,562">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Title}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Description}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date_Start}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: what's the problem with your codes? of what type is `e.Result`?

Comment: Use a lambda expression to iterate over your results and map them to a collection of your Newss data model. Then, set your listbox ItemsSource to the newss collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i guess right your myClient_getarvindNewsCompleted handler return data in xml string format. So you should first parse your xml data after that you should bind data to ListBox.ItemSource. Here are the solution this may be help you.

You need to add refrence of 'System.Xml.Linq' and 'System.Linq' dlls in your project

```
 void myClient_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
          {
string result = e.Result.ToString();
 List<Newss> listData = new List<Newss>();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);
            // Just as an example of using the namespace...
            //var b = doc.Element("NewDataSet").Value;
            foreach (var location in doc.Descendants("UserDetails"))
            {
                Newss data = new Newss();
                data.News_Title = location.Element("News_Title").Value;
                data.News_Description = location.Element("News_Description").Value;
                data.News_Date_Start = location.Element("Date_Start").Value;
                listData.Add(data);
            }
              listBox1.ItemsSource = listData;

          }
```